# How To Reference Map of Maps Variable in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below Jenkins pipeline and I am trying to echo out `SolutonName` and `TargetVersion` value. I tried different approaches and it either gave me error or not the result I wanted.

- If I use `echo "Solution Name: $solution['SolutionName']"`, it gave a result of `Solution Name: SolutionA={SolutionName=SolutionA, TargetVersion=1.0.0.0}['SolutionName']`, which is the map itself with `['SolutionName']` at the end.
- If I use `echo "Solution Name: ${solution.SolutionName}"`, it throws an error of `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field java.util.AbstractMap$SimpleImmutableEntry SolutionName`

```
def NodeLabel = 'windows'

// Solution
def SolutionMap = [
    SolutionA: [
        SolutionName: 'SolutionA',
        TargetVersion: '1.0.0.0'
    ],
    SolutionB: [
        SolutionName: 'SolutionB',
        TargetVersion: '2.1.0.0'
    ]
]

pipeline {
    agent { node { label "${NodeLabel}" } }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    SolutionMap.each { solution ->
                        stage(solution.key) {
                            echo "Solution Name: ${solution['SolutionName']}"
                            echo "Solution Name: ${solution['TargetVersion']}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, apparently I need to call:

`echo "Solution Name: $Solution.value.SolutionName"`

So it seems like calling `$Solution` does not assume it wants its `value` so I need to call `$Solution.value` to get the value and from there call `.SolutionName` to get the child value.